# Magento 1 checkbox issue in the Payment Methods section from adminhtml

Tags: magento-1, ajax, checkbox

I have a custom checkbox in the payment method:

```
<input  class="required-entry" type="checkbox" value="1" name="test" />
```

I checked the checkbox and I changed the shipping method. After the ajax reload my checkbox is unchecked.

If I add the attribute `checked='checked'` (to be my default checked). I changed the shipping method and after ajax reload my checkbox remained checked.

I tried to add the `checked='checked'` attribute via prototype(included directly in the template), like:

```
$$('#sepa_payment_adyen input[type="checkbox"]').invoke('observe','click',function(field) {
        if(this.checked){
            this.setAttribute('checked','checked');
        }else{
            this.removeAttribute('checked');
        }
});
```

It adds the `checked` attribute but after the ajax reload from shipping it remained unchecked. How can I fix this ? All of the inputs from my payment method selected kept they value, except this checkbox.